# Different css files to a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I want to include a css file to a jquery plugin.
I can choose one css file from several css files I have.

The plugin shouldn't work without a css file because it will be unordered - the user of this plugin must specify which css file she wants.
I want include the css file in such way I can change tomorrow easily.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Without css it will be *unstyled*, not 'unordered.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your plug-in needs to load in, or have the url of, a css file then I'd suggest any of the following:

1. have the plug-in show an text input element *requesting* the url of the preferred CSS stylesheet, or
2. pass a stylesheet as one of the plug-in's arguments, for example: `$('#element').plugIn({'stylesheet':'example.com/css/stylesheet1.css'})`

I'd probably *also* specify a set of default styles in the plug-in itself, so that the plug-in has some defaults to work from.

Further to all of the above, though, if your plug-in assigns `class`, or `id`, names to elements in your mark-up it's probably worth including a comment in your plug-in outlining the various names that are assigned, and under what circumstances, and simply suggest to the users that they add css for those names in their usual css, or in the head of their document.

Comment: can you explain more about set of default styles you mentioned in your answer? how exactly will you do it?